# Retrieve First Maximum Value With other Attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

This is my Database table :

[image]

I want to retrieve maximum `QueueNumber` and also `counterID` of same Maximum `QueueNumber` row. I have tried this query

```
SELECT MAX(QueueNumber),
       CounterID 
FROM tblQueue 
group by CounterID
```

but it I only get 3 records and I only want the maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sub-query in condition

```
select * from tblQueue
where QueueNumber = (select max(QueueNumber) from tblQueue)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
Select top 1 * from tblQueue order by QueueNumber desc
```